# How to create Custom runner

Tags: cloud9-ide

I'm trying to create a new Run button using "custom runner" in order to automatize compilation of C++ files. I mean, I want to create a new Run button that makes `g++ -o ...` when it's pressed.

I have seen the tutorial for making it, but is not helpful at all, not well explained. [Custom Runner Cloud9 tuto](https://docs.c9.io/custom_runners.html)

> In the Run panel (usually at the bottom of the UI), click the 'Runner' text input and choose 'New Runner'. In the new Runner file that's now opened, you can configure your runner using a simple JSON format.

Where can I find the "Runner text input", I cannot create any one! Here is a capture, what I'm seeing (still cannot upload images :( ) 
[Cloud9 Image](http://picpaste.com/pics/CapturaCloud9-YfSfEvMV.1411458227.PNG)

BTW, i'm running Cloud9 in Ubuntu14.04 BeagleBone Black.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have done it within Cloud9 webpage but I cannot see the same options in BBB->Cloud9

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot I noticed you're using an old version of Cloud9 on the BeagleBone Black, which doesn't support the custom Runners functionality. The documentation at https://docs.c9.io is based on the hosted, new version of Cloud, which does offer this functionality.

Comment: Any idea if I can get the latest version for BBB? GitHub is not the latest one, I tried it...

Comment: Not yet. We'll open source the new version of Cloud9 in the near future, but can't give you an ETA yet.

Comment: OK, in that case, is possible to create any script in order to launch >make ... style commands?